# How can I parse a json and extract to different case classes depending of its content

Tags: scala, json4s

I'm trying to parse different types of events in json format using json4s. I have written some case classes to represent the different events all inheriting from a base class `Event`:

```
  abstract class Event{ def EventType : String }
  case class StartSession(val EventType: String, val Platform: String) extends Event
  case class AdView(val EventType: String, val EventSubtype: String) extends Event
```

This is the function I use to parse the `StartSession` event:

```
  def parser(json: String): Event = {
    val parsedJson = parse(json)
    val s = parsedJson.extract[StartSession]
    return s
  }
```

This function will correctly parse a json like `{"EventType":"StartSession","Platform":"Portal"}`

I am looking for a way to generalize the parser function so I can use it to parse all types of events that inherits from `Event` and then do pattern matching over the return value of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type hints provide the solution to the problem. If you have a polymorphic type, such as `Event`, the type hint (here `EventType`) tells json4s into which actual type a json object should be deserialized.

For reference, have a look at the [github page of json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s). There is a section called "**Serializing polymorphic Lists**".

Since the type hint is only necessary for deserialization, we can get rid of the field `EventType` in `Event`.

```
abstract class Event
case class StartSession(Platform: String) extends Event
case class AdView(EventSubtype: String) extends Event
```

We need to bring a `Formats` instance into the scope of `extract`. The instance tells json4s how to perform deserialization. In our case, we need to specialize `typeHintFieldName` and `typeHints`. The first is the key of our type hint, in the example it is `"EventType"`. The latter is a mapping from string values to classes. If we are using the class name as value, then `ShortTypeHints` will do the trick. Othwerise, we could implement our own, specialized `TypeHints`.

A concrete solution could look as follows:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
  val json =
    s"""
       |[
       |  {
       |    "EventType": "StartSession",
       |    "Platform": "Portal"
       |  },
       |  {
       |    "EventType": "AdView",
       |    "EventSubtype": "SpecializedView"
       |  }
       |]
     """.stripMargin
  implicit val formats = new DefaultFormats {
    override val typeHintFieldName: String = "EventType"
    override val typeHints: TypeHints =
      ShortTypeHints(
        List(classOf[StartSession], classOf[AdView])
      )
  }
  val parsedJson = parse(json)
  val s = parsedJson.extract[List[Event]]
  println(s)
}
```